# I'm trying to use the MySQL NOT IN command, but to no avail, could anyone point out the error in my syntax?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
(SELECT s
FROM enrolls
WHERE s)
NOT IN
(SELECT s
FROM likes
WHERE s);
```

I've got two tables, `enrolls` and `likes`, and I'm trying to find s from enrolls where all of the tuples of s `likes` and `enrolls` have in common are removed (or `enrolls - likes`, basically).

I get the following error, though:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'NOT IN (SELECT s FROM likes WHERE s)' at line 4

Comment: Remove the `()` enclosing the first part of your `SELECT`, before the `NOT IN()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first set of parenthesis are improperly splitting your `s NOT IN` clause:

```
SELECT s
FROM enrolls
WHERE s NOT IN
    (
    SELECT s
    FROM likes
    WHERE s
    )
```

Comment: Thank you. Odd, my professor wrote it with the parentheses in class.